# Vue Router Optional Parameter on Parent Doesn't Render Child

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following setup in my vue router (v4.0.13):

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/:lang(en|fr)?",
    component: Layout, //Top-level component that contains the basic elements (sidebar, header, footer).
    children: [
      {
        path: "",
        name: "Home",
        component: Home,
      },
      {
        path: "other",
        name: "Other",
        component: Other,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

with Layout, Home, Other being my components. The problem is that the following routes don't render the Home component:

`/`  or  `/en`.

If I remove the `?` and make the parameter non optional then `/en` renders the Home component correctly but the `/` route doesn't work anymore.

What am I missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-router-starter-uudjvp?file=src%2FApp.vue).

Comment: Thank you for looking into it @tony19. I found the problem, as the last child view I had a catch-all 404 page with
```
{
        path: ":catchAll(.*)",
        name: "NotFound",
        component: NotFound,
}
```
and although it was matching the first one as well it was showing the not found page instead.